# self restart service (not to ask system)

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I need to restart service I'm developing. I don't wont to ask service manager to do this in case of error. I need somehow to do this in my code. Is there are any possibilities to solve my problem?

**Reason I need that:**

I need this restart in case of some particular exception. I could close my application in case of thous exceptions and setup service manager to recovery service.

As I understood service manager will restart service in both cases -  when errors are generated in event viewer and when service is stooped.

It is not good for my if service will be restarted in case of errors in event viewer, because my application generates some errors in event viewer I still can't understand. Those errors have no influence on service work quality. I need just restart in case of service stop ore in case of my exceptions I need to handle.

Comment: Under what sorts of situations do you need to restart? as windows can handle all that for you if you let it.

Comment: Do you need to protect against your service crashes in production at ur client? Or do you need to halt and re-start working service for debugging and developing it at ur own box? What exactly are Services Manager errors are you afraid of ? Why do you want to devise some hack instead of using standard and compatible methods vis SM ?

Comment: I have a utility program that my service runs when it wants to be restarted (which happens due to an update being available). It passes the parameters to the utility to tell it the name of its service, and then carries on as usual (in case the utility fails). The utility then uses the normal service control API to stop, update and start the service. Nothing too clever.

Comment: @mj2008 Such a utility program is also available from Microsoft: [sc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: @TOndrej: thanks for that link. However, to do what mj2008 is doing, you'd need multiple sc executions and thus still require your own exe or bat to orchestrate them.

Comment: I would not solve it like this. I would put service logic in a DLL. Then when it's time to update, unload, update and reload. Modern programmers have forgotten the art of servicing a program whilst it is running.

Comment: That's nice while API does not change. And if there is not much internal state.

Comment: @TOndrej There is no restart option for sc, and it cannot do other things like copy in the new service executable. Handy to know about though.

Comment: @arioch service api doesn't change though does it. It is stable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i mean your main exe, that u describe like bridge, common service provider just switching implementation DLLs on upgrade. If you want your windows service to keep running while switching DLLs - then it would be the service providing the public API. And the topic about windows servicec, not just application with plugins.

Comment: @mj2008 all Windows NT had command-line start/stop for services. Before XP it was called net.exe with start and stop options.

Comment: I build my services as a shell wrapping around a DLL, and the core of the work is done in the DLL. The service can run non-stop, and when installing an update, I don't stop the service, I just save a flag so the service knows it should stop its work, then replace the DLL, and resume the service. When updating, the service EXE is never replaced because all it does is tells the DLL to do whatever task it has.

Comment: I have added reason why I need manual restart. Maybe it will clarify situation. Is there such API function like "PleaseRestartMe"?

Comment: service restart is nothing about events viewer at all.
just care to report windows when you stopped cleanly.
if no report, windows assumes an error and takes appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to setup your service with restart on error flags.
What is error ? Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685939.aspx
You exit you application and report of clean exit to Operating System.
If you do not, then Service Manager assumes you crashed and could not make proper reports. It is up to you to Halt your service application with or without proper reporting it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996.aspx

Below is the 1st version of answer, assuming topic starter need "hot upgrade" functionality. It still may be used, yet is redundant to just auto-restart on crashes.

---

You make two services.

One is worker, another is monitor and restarter - like obsolete Interbase/Firebird scheme, like some trojan viri do, and so on.

Or one is worker, and the second is back-up worker silently tracking the changes, if 1st crashes it assumes the leading role and spawns next back-up worker. That is how shadow db servers do.

The latter is only needed to have near zero latency between crash and resuming work, otherwise it is way too expensive. The former is fragile scheme, obsoleted by standard win32 services properties.

Answer (score 1):

Move your service's work into a thread. Then the service can simply terminate and recreate the thread when needed without having to restarted service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Windows already provides 'restarting a service'. No need to do it also in your service.